# SSD: MacBook Pro Retina 15" (A1398) and 13" (A1425) compatibility?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

Can I use an SSD from MacBook Pro retina A1398 in a A1425? Will it work ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is *yes*, they both support 2.5" 9mm hard drives (be that SSD or traditional).

The Retina 2012/Early 2013 13" Macbook Pro ([A1425](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=A1425)), and the Retina 2012 through to the Mid-2014 15" Macbook Pros ([A1398](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=A1398)), take the same disks.

Hope that helps.